# How can I get a legit(unstolen) Falkreath Jail Key?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I have a habit of, when I've been arrested, 'borrowing' a key to the jail I get arrested in, then using it to easily reclaim any stolen goods for future visits. Well, I got arrested in Falkreath for a crime I don't remember, on my first visit there I already somehow had a bounty of 1000, and pickpocketted a key off a guard. Well it's marked as stolen, how could I get one that isn't?

Comment: You probably can't *find* one—why would there be an unowned jail key anywhere in the game? You'll have to settle for a stolen one or somehow launder it to remove its stolen status.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie would it work if I killed the only soldier in the jail, and in fact the only one in falkreath with a key, waited for him to respawn (because they do) then killed him again, since he should have respawned with a key?

Comment: Would it work to what? To mark your key as not stolen? No, that would just make an extra key.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Well yea, But I could give my extra key to wifey and have an unstolen key for myself.

Comment: I'm still unclear where you think this unstolen key would come from.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Isn't stealing if you kill him first.

Comment: If you're sure that works, why did you ask the question in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to place the stolen key in a regular thug's inventory by pickpocketing (like a bandit or something).

If you kill him and loot his corpse, the key should have lost its "stolen" tag.

This worked for me with Equipment, dont know if keys have other rules.

Comment: It... should work. Don't see why not...

Answer (score -3):

i'm pretty sure you are not going to find that key anywhere,especially unstolen.but there is another way to easily jack out of jail.ever heard of the skeleton key,if you get arrested,this will and might be the only thing you take into jail.and it is basically an unbreakable lock...you'll use in in jail to break out.

Comment: You don't get to keep the Skeleton key when going to jail.

Comment: Far better to get the lvl 100 lockpicking perk anyway.

Comment: @kotekzot yes you do.

Comment: he isn't asking another way to break out of prison besides the key, he's asking about how to find a key unstolen.